# How to subtract two date columns & calculate the duration in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have tree columns in one of the tables : check-in time and check-out time and billableHours. Check-in & check-out are `date` columns, `billableHours` is `varchar` and would like to format like this: `HH:MM`.

I could use following query

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, (Checkout - checkIn), 108) 
FROM WorkTrackingLog
```

but it returns `HH:MM:SS`

Question #1:

How do I subtract checkout-checkin and get billableHours in this format - `HH:MM`?

Now once I get HH:MM from check-in & check-out date, I would like to add HH:MM and get the totalDuration in other table.

For example lets say I have three records:

Table # 1:

```
TicketId |  billableHours 
1001    | 05:04 
1001    | 12:19
1001    | 02:16
```

Table # 2

```
TicketId | totalDuration
1001    |   19:39
```

Question # 2

How do I convert `HH:Mm` to `int` and add multiple records together to get `totalDuration`. Total duration can be `varchar` format.

Make sense?

Thank you in advance for your input/feedback.

Comment: **Don't store formated data; store raw data.** Use a numeric/float type for hours and fractional hours, or an integral type for minutes. Only format when you display the data to an end user.

Comment: And use the **appropriate datatype**! If you need to store numerical values like `billableHours` - store them in a numeric datatype, not as `varchar`! If those are stored as numbers as they should, then it's a piece of cake to sum them up into `totalDuration` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

Question #1

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), 
   DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, CheckOut, CheckIn), 0), 114)
```

Question #2

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), SUM(Datediff(minute,convert(datetime,'00:00:00',108), 
  convert(datetime,BillableHours,108))), 114)
GROUP BY TicketId
```